# Btree details on Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, indexing, b-tree

How can i know details about an index on postgresql like how many nodes, and tree height?

It is possible to access the data structure itself?

i havent found any catalog tables that exposes such that detailed information

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be better to ask such things on postgres mailing list. More chances to find someone with knowledge of postgres internals. Also you can always read and alter postgres source code for such thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the bt_metap function in the pageinspect extension.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pageinspect.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use pgstattuple extension.

```
create extension pgstattuple;
SELECT * FROM pgstatindex('your_index_name');
```

For example,

```
ycsb=# select * from pgstatindex('usertable_pkey');
 version | tree_level | index_size | root_block_no | internal_pages | leaf_pages | empty_pages | deleted_pages | avg_leaf_density | leaf_fragmentation 
---------+------------+------------+---------------+----------------+------------+-------------+---------------+------------------+--------------------
       2 |          3 | 5488721920 |         44337 |           4464 |     665545 |           0 |             0 |               52 |                 11
(1 row)
```

You can refer to documentation;
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstattuple.html